# Toggle menu when clicked outside div while button is in the header

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, menu, toggle

I'm trying to hide my **offcanvas** menu while i'm clicking outside the div where the menu is in.
It is a menu which only appears while the bootstrap xs class will be loaded.

My button is inside my header and the menu is a page on his own.

this is how my button looks like:

```
<p class="pull-left visible-xs">
<?php if($data['title'] == 'Producten' || $data['title'] == 'Winkeltjes' || $data['title'] == 'Home'){?>
    <button type="button" onClick="document.getElementById('sidebar').scrollIntoView();" 
    class="btn btn-primary btn-default" data-toggle="offcanvas">
        Filters
    </button>
<?php }
</p>
```

I've found a couple ways on stackoverflow and tried those, but these all didnt workout with my offcanvas div. the div that should be opened has the following class and id:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar">
```

I don't have any functions anymore at the moment.

hopefully I've give you guys enough information and I'm looking forward to any reply.

Comment: Please don't tag questions with `jQuery` unless you want a jQuery answer... Do you? :)

Comment: i'm sorry, it was a recommended tag and i didn't know how to tag it else

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code...

```
function hideWhenClickedElseWhere(container, callback){
        $(document).mouseup(function (e){
            if (!container.is(e.target) && // if the target of the click isn't the container...
                container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
            {
                callback();
            }
        });
    }
```

The first argument is the nodes in which you don't want to close the menu when clicked. 
The Second argument is the callback - what should we do if clicked elsewhere.

```
hideWhenClickedElseWhere( $(".buttonClass, .menuClass") ), function(){
   $(".menuClass").hide();
   $(".buttonClass").removeClass("acctive");
});
```

Comment: OP did not want a jQuery solution, just tagged it incorrectly. See comments.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i still didn't figure it out. I've tried it with id's instead off classes because the classes where my data is in, are standard bootstrap classes. With my #id's in it, there isn't happening anything. Perhaps i'm just adding it to the wrong page

Answer (score 0):

Use this code..

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
        if (
            !$(e.target).hasClass('menuClass') &&
            !$(e.target).hasClass('') &&
            $(e.target).parents('.buttonClass').length == 0 &&
            $(e.target).parents('.menuClass').length == 0
            ) {
                $(".menuClass").hide();
                $(".buttonClass").removeClass("acctive");
        }
    });
```